# Socket timeout exception thrown after long delays

Tags: android, sockets, timeout, delay

I set my socket's timeout using the [Socket.setSoTimeout(54000)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket#setSoTimeout(int)) API

In most cases, if the server has not responded, I notice that after the elapsed time (9 mins in this case) the API throws the expected "SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" exception.

However, in Samsung(OS version 23)(did not happen with a Nexus 6P) devices I see that it could take anywhere between 45 mins to 180 mins when the device goes into "Idle mode". 
(I determine the device's idle state using the [PowerManager#isDeviceInIdleMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isDeviceIdleMode()) API)

Is this expected ? 
Is there any solution to this problem, such that the socket times out at the set timeout ?

Also, my app is using the [Apache Http client 4.4.1.2](https://github.com/smarek/httpclient-android)
I also set the timeout on this via [HttpConnectionParams#setSoTimeout](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/params/HttpConnectionParams.html#setSoTimeout(org.apache.http.params.HttpParams,%20int))

Thank You!

Comment: @Kling Klang any reason "Android" was removed from the subject ?
I have not tried this on any other platform hence I restricted this to Android

Comment: Because it's already in the **tag** area, where it belongs. Tags must not be repeated in titles.